# Update table variable from the same table variable?

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I've got a table variable (`@t_var`) like this:

```
[RSIN]    [Grp]
 S-000001   1
 S-000002   2
 S-000003   1
 C-000002  null
 C-000003  null
```

I need to set **[Grp]** for **"C"**-types based on **[Grp]** for **"S"**-types with respective right parts. In the end I should get like this:

```
[RSIN]    [Grp]
 S-000001   1
 S-000002   2
 S-000003   1
 C-000002   2
 C-000003   1
```

The most obvious way I was trying to do:

```
UPDATE    @t_var
SET       [Grp] = B.[Grp]
FROM      @t_var A
LEFT JOIN @t_var B
       ON 'C'+RIGHT(A.[RSIN], 7) = B.[RSIN]
WHERE     LEFT(A.[RSIN],1) = 'S'
```

But Management Studio tell me something about it can't distinct which `@t_var` to use. This construct works fine when we talk about physical tables, but refuses to work when it comes to table variables.

Is there any elegant workaround but to create duplicate table variable like `@t_var2` and using it in join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @t_var table (RSIN char(8), Grp int);

insert @t_var
values 
  ('S-000001', 1),
  ('S-000002', 2),
  ('S-000003', 1),
  ('C-000002', null),
  ('C-000003', null)

;with x as (
    select b.rsin, a.grp, b.grp as prev
    from @t_var a
    inner join @t_var b on 'c'+right(a.[rsin], 7) = b.[rsin]
    where left(a.[rsin],1) = 's' 
)
update x
set prev = grp

select * from @t_var
```

Answer (score 0):

Table names and column names can't be dynamic. They need to stay static

You need to use Dynamic SQL here

Read more about

1. [Building Dynamic SQL In a Stored Procedure](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure)
2. [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)
3. [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Hoe this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE @t_var
SET [Grp] = CASE WHEN LEFT([RSIN], 1) = 'C'
                      AND RIGHT([RSIN], 1) = '2'
                 THEN 2
                 WHEN LEFT([RSIN], 1) = 'C'
                      AND ( RIGHT([RSIN], 1) = '1'
                         OR 
                         RIGHT([RSIN], 1) = '3' )
                 THEN 1
             END
```